# Overriding inner class' method in Interface

Tags: java

I have an interface in which I declare an inner class:

```
public interface myInterface 
{
    int count();    
    public class myInterfaceInnerClass
    {
        public void testOverride()
        {

        }
    }
}
```

And `class Test implements myInterface`:

```
public class Test implements myInterface
{

    public Test() 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public int count()
    {
        return 1;
    }

    //Here I would like to be able to override the inner class' method testOverride
}
```

Is it possible to override the inner class' method `testOverride` in `class Test`?

---

***EDIT:***

In response to comment made by O. Charlesworth, I came up with the following:

```
public interface myInterface 
{
    myInterface aInterface = new myInterfaceInnerClass();
    int count();

    public class myInterfaceInnerClass implements myInterface
    {
        @Override
        public int count() 
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return 0;
        }
        public void testOverride()
        {

        }
    }
}
```

In `class Test`:

```
public class Test implements myInterface
{
    public Test() 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public int count()
    {
        return 1;
    }
}
```

> Is it still possible to override the inner class' method testOverride
>   here in `class Test`?

Comment: This isn't clear; `Test` is implementing `myInterface`, it's not extending `myIntercaceInnerClass`; it doesn't make sense to talk about overrding a method of a class that you don't extend.

Comment: If there were two implementations of `myInterface` how should myInterfaceInnerClass behave?

Comment: @JimmyT. Could you please elaborate more, Jimmy? Thanks.

Comment: Why do you need to override the method?

Answer (score 1):

Here's something you can do:

```
import myInterface.myInterfaceInnerClass;

public class Test extends myInterfaceInnerClass implements myInterface {

    @Override public int count() {
      // ...
      return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void testOverride() {
      // ...
    }

}
```

Reason for `extend`ing class `myInterfaceInnerClass` (A picture > a million words):

[image]
<sub>(source: [gyazo.com](http://gyazo.com/009d091805db1c1639d2f41db48bae98.png))</sub>

Comment: I don't know why someone would want to go this route. Just specify the members in the interface itself then.

Comment: @Unheilig I think it's more clear now that `extends myInterfaceInnerClass` suits your question. As a side note, name `type`s in BlockCaseEachWord, not camelCaseEachWord. Semantics. :)

Comment: @Unihedron Thanks for suggestion. Coming from the Obj-C world. :-)

Comment: @Unihedron Just wondering, is it possible at all to not having to `extend` in this case, in case that `class Test` already has extended something? Thanks.

Comment: @Unheilig `class Test` `implements` `myInterface`, but `myInterface` does not inherit `myInterfaceInnerClass`. Hold on, I'll sketch you a picture.

Comment: @Unihedron perhaps `static` inner class is needed here and then override? I am not sure how. Thanks for pic in advance.

Comment: The whole point of the class structure there is that you do not inherit the methodology from the inner class, you merely gain access to it. In order to "override" a method, you need to be inheriting from a superclass. So you either need to extend the inner class or create a new inner class that extends the previous one.